# Persisted SAF URI from Google Drive changes after a few days, content is unreachable

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework

I'm persisting an URI obtained via SAF launched with the following intent:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT)
    .setType("application/json")
    .putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true)
    .putExtra("android.content.extra.FANCY", true)
    .putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_FILESIZE", true)
    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

I didn't use the `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag, because I don't need it. This initially works, and keeps working after activity is destroyed, at least for a few days. After a few days:

- The URI saved to my database is apparently no longer valid. `ContentResolver.persistedUriPermissions` doesn't show it. Yet, the file hasn't moved and wasn't renamed.
- `ContentResolver.persistedUriPermissions` does return a few URIs, but none can be resolved, despite being supposedly persisted. The error I get with `contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)` is: "Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.docs.storage" (as if it wasn't being found the day before!).

I have only tested with Google Drive for now, so I assumed the issue is related to it. I'm testing it with local storage, but I'll have to wait a few days to see the result. In the meantime: am I missing important flags on the Intent? Am I correct to save the URI as a string? Has this been known to happen to anyone else?

Comment: "am I missing important flags on the Intent?" -- no, but you can get rid of both of the flags that you have. Neither belong on that `Intent`. They are flags that you use to grant rights to others and to see if you received a grant. They are not flags to request a grant. "Am I correct to save the URI as a string?" -- that should be fine. "and keeps working after activity is destroyed, at least for a few days" -- I assume that you are calling `takePersistableUriPermission()` in `onActivityResult()`, when you first get the `Uri` back.

Comment: Ok that's good to know. I'm using `takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)`, but I'm not using `FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` anywhere else. Could this be the problem? The docs say "Only URI permissions granted with Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION can be persisted", I assumed they meant for it to be used on the SAF intent. I haven't found any reference to it in your blog posts.

Comment: "Could this be the problem?" -- no, that is used by the `DocumentsProvider` (in this case, Google Drive) to tell the system that it is OK to allow these permissions to be granted. It feels like that in your case Google Drive is proactively revoking permissions after a certain amount of time.

Comment: Local storage URI still works after a few days, so this seems to be a Google Drive problem. Not much to be done about it I suppose. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @CommonsWare you might want to convert your comments to an answer.

Comment: @Bip901: None of my comments really answer the question -- they were more exploring edges of the problem in hopes that I might come up with something. The closest thing to an answer is Nicholas's "this seems to be a Google Drive problem".

Comment: Same issue when using Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

I'm running in to this issue too. It seems to be ok with Uris selected from the Files app, but the Google Drive Uris that I persist as Strings will stop working after an hour or so (a seemingly random delay, but after an app restart). On app startup, I could see that the Uri is still returned by `getPersistedUriPermissions()`, but when used in `mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(context, uri)` it would throw an `IllegalArgumentException`. After this, it would not be returned by `getPersistedUriPermissions()` anymore, and if I try to access it again, it would throw a `java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA`.

Comment: You answer seems more like a comment. For an answer it should not only talk about similar case but a solution to how to solve this issue. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer